# Validation error "xs:element must end with a '>' delimiter"

Tags: html, xsd-validation

Why the W3C validator gives the following Problem when checking the Code below:

> "Not well formed: The end-tag for element type "xs:element" must end
>   with a '>' delimiter.

Schema:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="filmliste">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="film">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element ref='titel'/>
                        <xs:element ref='erscheinungsjahr'/>
                        <xs:element ref='regisseur'/>
                        <xs:element ref='schauspieler'/>
                        <xs:element ref='genre'/>
                        <xs:element ref='bewertung'/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:element name='film' maxOccurs='unbounded'/>
        <xs:element name='titel' type='xs:string' use='required' maxOccurs='1'/>
        <xs:element name='erscheinungsjahr' type='xs:positiveInteger' use='required' maxOccurs='1'/>
        <xs:element name='regisseur' type='xs:string' use='required' minOccurs='1'/>
        <xs:element name='schauspieler' type='xs:string' use='required' minOccurs='1'/>
        <xs:element name='genre' type='xs:string' use='required' minOccurs='1'/>
        <xs:element name='bewertung' type='xs:double' use='required' minOccurs='1'/>
    </xs:element name="filmliste">
</xs:schema>
```

The XML document Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<filmliste author='Max' datum='20.01.2018' xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="filmlistexsd.xsd">

    <film>

        <titel> Der Marsianer </titel>

        <erscheinungsjahr> 2015 </erscheinungsjahr>

        <regisseur> Ridley Scott </regisseur>

        <schauspieler> Matt Damon, Jessica Chastain </schauspieler>

        <bewertung> 8,1 </bewertung>

    </film> 

    <film>

        <titel> Joy - Alles außer gewöhnlich </titel>

        <erscheinungsjahr> 2015 </erscheinungsjahr>

        <regisseur> David O. Russel </regisseur>  

        <schauspieler> Jennifer Lawrene, Bradley Cooper, Robert De Niro</schauspieler>

        <genre> Drama, Komödie </genre>  

    </film>

    <film>

        <titel> Der Herr der Ringe – Die Gefährten </titel>

        <erscheinungsjahr> 2001 </erscheinungsjahr>

        <regisseur> Peter Jackson </regisseur>

        <schauspieler> Elijah Wood, Viggo Mortensen, Orlando Bloom, Ian McKellen </schauspieler> 

        <bewertung> 9,2 </bewertung>

    </film>

</filmliste>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. SO is aimed at providing a Q&A knowledge base, so, ideally, you would simplify the included source code to be as small as possible while still demonstrating the described problem. However my feeling is that the problem giving the error message is the </xs:element name="filmliste">, which shouldn't have the 'name' attribute.

Comment: I can confirm @MandyShaw's analysis. Do not put attributes on closing elements.